# Gibbs sampling confusion

Tags: probability, gibbs

I'm just wondering if i'm doing this process correctly i'm a little confused as to the answers i'm getting:

I have $P(x=0,y=0) = P(x=1,y=1) = 0.5$ and $P(x=0,y=1) = P(x=1,y=0) = 0$

I calculated $P(x=1 | y = 0) = 0 $ and $P(x=1 | y = 1) = 1 $.

I'm not trying to do a gibbs sampling with the starting point $x=1$ and $y=1$.

EDIT:  I think i'm just confused with how gibbs sampling works, so if you could give me a sample step or an example in general that would be great.